# golang http.Post request returns with response 404

Tags: http, go, http-post, github-api

I have written a go code to create a issue in a project in my github reposiory. I am using parameters as mentioned here [https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue][1]

But I am getting response with status 404. Below is my code.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    param := map[string]string{"title": "issue1", "body": "aassddrff", "assignee": "vigneshkm"}

    query, _ := json.Marshal(param)
    queryUrl := "https://api.github.com/repos/vigneshkm/first_repo/issues"

    fmt.Println("query:", string(query))
    resp, err := http.Post(queryUrl, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(query))

    fmt.Println("query_status : ", resp.StatusCode, "err : ", err)
    resp.Body.Close()
}
```

I am a beginner to web programming and I am not able to understand my mistake in this code. Kindly help me :)

Comment: What's the response body?

Comment: some apis response by their own convention, which could be here too. if I were you, would've checked cookies and possible redirection to that url

Comment: Your API saying `Not found` issue,  even I checked it with postman, first check your API, does it actually exist or not ?

Comment: @Peter I tried to read body as following "newBuf := bytes.NewBuffer(buf) ; num, ret := newBuf.ReadFrom(json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Buffered()) ; fmt.Println("string:", newBuf.String())" and i see the output as nil.  did u mean the same or something else??

Comment: You get HTTP 404 because this is a POST request which requires authentication. See: https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Access to https://github.com/settings/tokens
2) Click "Generate new token"
3) Copy the token.
4) Paste the token to "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE" in below. (I mean, remove "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE" and paste your token there).

```
$ cat main.go 
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    param := map[string]string{"title": "issue1", "body": "aassddrff", "assignee": "vigneshkm"}

    query, _ := json.Marshal(param)
    queryUrl := "https://api.github.com/repos/vigneshkm/first_repo/issues?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE"

    fmt.Println("query:", string(query))
    resp, err := http.Post(queryUrl, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(query))

    fmt.Println("query_status : ", resp.StatusCode, "err : ", err)
    resp.Body.Close()
}
```

This is the result in my environment.

```
$ go run main.go 
query: {"assignee":"vigneshkm","body":"aassddrff","title":"issue1"}
query_status :  201 err :  <nil>
```

https://github.com/vigneshkm/first_repo/issues/2

Comment: this solution works.. I am now trying to create the accesss token via programme or code.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing access token while request.

```
queryUrl := "https://api.github.com/repos/vigneshkm/first_repo/issues?access_token=" + OAUTH_TOKEN
```

Check this [document](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication)